# OSX add NSMenu to NSView, this view return in NSOutlineViewDelegate, but not popup

Tags: objective-c, macos

```
- (NSView *)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn item:(id)item
{
    NSView *view = [outlineView makeViewWithIdentifier:[item itemIdentifier] owner:nil];
    NSMenu *menu = [self.menuDictionary objectForKey:[item itemIdentifier]];
    if (menu != nil) {
        view.menu = menu;
    }
    return view;
}
```

code, when I right click this view, cannot popup my menu.
in some reason, I want to add menu by code, not in xib.
Someone knews about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want a menu to appear when a user right-clicks a row in an NSOutlineView. You can do that by just setting the menu for the outline view:

```
NSMenu *aMenu = // a menu;
[self.outlineView setMenu:aMenu];
```

Comment: Thanks, I try to add Menu to outlineView and all NSTableRowView subviews, but also can not popup

Comment: You should not be adding the menu to NSTableRowViews. Are you saying my answer does not work?

Comment: Yes, I have tried add NSMenu to self.outlineView, not add to NSTableRowView, by code. not work. and use xib add menu to outlineView that can work...I don't know why...

Comment: Can you post the code you used to set the menu to the outlineView?

Comment: Thanks, I succeed. but why cannot add to NSTableRowView or the view in outlineView :viewForTableColumn:item: .  in cell-base outlineView I can add menu to cell

Comment: NSTableRowView is responsible for displaying attributes associated with the row (ie. selection highlight and group row look), and not for displaying a menu. A custom NSView can have a menu. But you will have to subclass the NSView, add the NSMenu to the subclass, and then display the menu somehow (ie. [NSMenu popUpContextMenu:withEvent:forView:]. You cannot simply add it to the view in [NSOutlineView outlineView:viewForTableColumn:item:].

Comment: Also, if my answer does answer your question. Please mark it as so. Thank you.